# should + distance_function in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to give weighting to geographical proximity in values returned in Elasticsearch. I want close proximity to be less important than some fields (eg legal_name) but more important than others.

From the docs, it looks like the current way to do that is with [distance_feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-distance-feature-query.html). However, the should condition I created never alters the results in any relevant way. In fact, if I take out the must values, it looks like scores are based off of *further distance*. That is, higher scores correlate to further distances. What I want instead, of course, is for close distance to be rewarding the score. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong appreciated...

(of note - the 'coordinate' field is of type geo_point)

Simplified doc

```
{
_index: "organizations",
_type: "_doc",
_id: "3",
_version: 9,
_seq_no: 16944,
_primary_term: 5,
found: true,
_source: {
   id: 3,
   legal_name: "Air Canada",
   operating_name: "Air Canada",
   ...
   coordinate: "43.85133,-79.36572",
}
}
```

Query

````
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Air Canada",
                    "fields": ["legal_name^7","operating_name^7","interest_areas^4","city^3", "description","state","country"
                    ]
                }},
                {"term" : { "organization_type.keyword": "Sponsor" }},
                {"term" : { "approved" : true }}
            ],
            "should": {
              "distance_feature": {
                "field": "coordinate",
                "pivot": "25km",
                "origin": [43.63, -79.3716],
                "boost": 5.0
              }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I gave up on distance_feature and used a gaussian function instead.

{
"from": 0,
"size": 20,
"query": {

```
"function_score": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "national bank",
            "fields": ["legal_name^0.7", "operating_name^0.7", "interest_areas^0.4", "city^0.4", "description^0.4", "state^0.1", "country^0.1"]
        }},
        {"term" : { "organization_type.keyword": "Sponsor" }},
        {"term" : { "approved" : true }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "boost": "1",
  "boost_mode": "sum",
  "functions": [{
    "gauss": {
      "coordinate": {
        "origin": { "lat": 43.63, "lon": -79.3716 },
        "offset": "500km",
        "decay": 0.5,
        "scale": "100km"
      }
    },
    "weight": 1
  }]
}
```

}
}`

Comment: with gauss applied to time field I've noticed drop in performance. Also, in your orig query, it might be that your base query with 3 "must" clauses dominates the final score too much, and hence the additive "should" clause does not move the base score anywhere. You could try lowering the boosts inside "fields" (as you did in the answer)